# In Regex how to match in between the words?

Tags: regex

I want to write the regex pattern which should match the string in between also.

For example:

I have writtenthe regex pattern like this

```
^((?!mystring).)*$
```

Which means match words which doesnot contain mystring. But i want regex pattern to match like this.

```
mystringabcdfrevrgf
```

regex matcher should return

```
abcdfrevrgf
```

How will i achieve this, Please help Thanks in advance.

**Answer:**

```
((?!mystring)(.*))$
```

Comment: I think you need a regex replace then and not a match. See @Tim's answer. He got all bases covered.

Comment: Your "answer" - `((?!mystring)(.*))$` - matches `ystringabcdfrevrgf`, not `abcdfrevrgf`.  Unless you're using .NET with the RightToLeft option selected, that is.  What flavor *are* you using, anyway?  Please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to remove `mystring` from the string you're matching?

As in (Python example):

```
>>> re.sub("mystring", "", "mystringabcdfrevrgf")
'abcdfrevrgf'
```

which of course only makes sense if `mystring` is in fact a regex, like

```
>>> re.sub("my.*?g", "", "xyzmystringabcdfrevrgf")
'xyzabcdfrevrgf'
```

Otherwise, plain string manipulation functions would be faster, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Each match returned by regular expression engine is a continuous string.
Given a text XYZ and the goal of XZ, the engine can either return X and Z as 2 matches and then leave concatenation up to user, it can match Y and do a replace with empty string. It cannot match XZ directly because it's not a continuous string. If you look at internal implementations of regular expression engines, you will see that each match is usually defined with a pair of integers (matchStartIndex, matchEndIndex or matchStartIndex, matchLength), making it impossible for a match to leave out characters in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this:

```
var str = 'mystringabcdfrevrgf';
var regex = /^mystring(.*)$/;

var result = str.match(regex)[1];
//result contains 'abcdfrevrgf'
```